# Why MySQL REGEXP [:space:] match with character that are not in the data at all

Tags: mysql, regex

I have this condition in my query

```
SELECT r.roomid as room_id, up.name as partner_name, up.avatar as partner_avatar, m.message as last_partner_message, ...
...
WHERE uo.id = "${ownerId}"
AND ( (up.name = "" OR up.name IS NULL) 
OR ( up.name LIKE "${keyword}%" 
OR up.name REGEXP "[:space:]${keyword}*" )
```

> context:
>
> - up = user partner, uo = user owner.
> - ${value} is javascript variable in string literal

When I insert the `keyword` as `z` It is showing the result like this:

```
"data": [
    {
      "room_id": "Nngdys/v2EDHAY4V",
      "partner_name": "Mai Toyota", /* please take a look at every partner_name value */
      "partner_avatar": "example_url_image.com",
      "last_partner_message": null,
      "last_chat_minute": null
    },
    {
      "room_id": "7GEf2kRUYgLrpgzD",
      "partner_name": "Georgmain Lo",
      "partner_avatar": "example_url_image.com",
      "last_partner_message": null,
      "last_chat_minute": null
    },
    {
      "room_id": "9Ji1w+mgvMRy9BzH",
      "partner_name": "Toyota Mai",
      "partner_avatar": "example_url_image.com",
      "last_partner_message": null,
      "last_chat_minute": null
    },
    {
      "room_id": "ISkm3GYz7oDu4x5w",
      "partner_name": "Georgmain Lo",
      "partner_avatar": "example_url_image.com",
      "last_partner_message": null,
      "last_chat_minute": null
    },
    {
      "room_id": "CmY9HDG8YuadjwvN",
      "partner_name": "Georgmain Lo",
      "partner_avatar": "example_url_image.com",
      "last_partner_message": null,
      "last_chat_minute": null
    }
  ]
```

**As you can see there is not even `z` in the `partner_name` value. Turns out this result happens for every single character input in `keyword`.** But if I insert two characters or more it is just does fine.

I don't understand why.

**UPDATE:**

The problem seems in the REGEXP here. Just look at this
[image]

`[:space:]${single_char}*` will match every value that has space in it.

> Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/217a49/2

Comment: Read the [Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) carefully. 

Pattern class name needs in doubled square brackets, and you must use `OR up.name REGEXP "[[:space:]]${keyword}*"`.

Comment: @Akina still doesn't work.

Comment: Create a fiddle which reproduces your issue.

Comment: @Akina I've added the fiddle, please kindly check it

Comment: Note that `*` means zero or more matches. Use `[[:space:]]s+` instead.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  `[[:space:]]` works in 8.0; `\s` works in 5.x

Comment: @slaakso - you mean `[[:space:]]+` for 1 or more whitespace in 8.0.  Or `\s+` for one or more in 5.x.  What you have is "one space followed by at least one 's'".

Comment: @Akina - That is "one space followed by the characters in the $keyword, except that the _last letter_ can be missing or repeated.  Sounds wrong.

Comment: @slaakso That + sign works for me!

Comment: @slaakso You may want write that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The comment as an answer:

Note that `*` means zero or more matches. The `+` meand one or more. You may want to use `[[:space:]]s+` instead.

Comment: btw it still doesn't make sense for me tho, if * can mean zero then the minimal match value for this `[[:space:]]s*` should be ` s`. So why [[:space:]]s* can match the value that there is even an s in it?